# Discrepancies in NDSolve Solution Between 4D and its Reduced 3D Counterpart

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy

I have two systems, a 4D system and a 3D system. The 3D system is a reduction of the 4D system in such a way that:

```
(* 
y1[t] = x2[t] - x1[t]
Thus: 
-y1[t] = x1[t] - x2[t]
y1'[t] = x2'[t] - x1'[t]

y2[t] = x3[t] - x1[t]
Thus: 
-y2[t] = x1[t] - x3[t]
y2'[t] = x3'[t] - x1'[t]

y3[t] = x4[t] - x1[t]
Thus: 
-y1[t] = x1[t] - x4[t]
y1'[t] = x4'[t] - x1'[t]
*)

w = 1; k = 1/5; r = 1/4; a = 5/4; n = 4;

eqs = {
x1'[t]==w+(k/n)*(Sin[x2[t]-x1[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(x2[t]-x1[t])] + Sin[x3[t]-x1[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(x3[t]-x1[t])] + Sin[x4[t]-x1[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(x4[t]-x1[t])]),

x2'[t]==w+(k/n)*(Sin[x1[t]-x2[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(x1[t]-x2[t])] + Sin[x3[t]-x2[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(x3[t]-x2[t])] + Sin[x4[t]-x2[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(x4[t]-x2[t])]),

x3'[t]==w+(k/n)*(Sin[x1[t]-x3[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(x1[t]-x3[t])] + Sin[x2[t]-x3[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(x2[t]-x3[t])] + Sin[x4[t]-x3[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(x4[t]-x3[t])]),

x4'[t]==w+(k/n)*(Sin[x1[t]-x4[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(x1[t]-x4[t])] + Sin[x2[t]-x4[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(x2[t]-x4[t])] + Sin[x3[t]-x4[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(x3[t]-x4[t])])
};

eqsPD = {
y1'[t]==(k/n)*((Sin[-y1[t]+a]-r*Sin[-2*y1[t]]+Sin[y2[t]-y1[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(y2[t]-y1[t])]+Sin[y3[t]-y1[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(y3[t]-y1[t])]) - (Sin[y1[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*y1[t]]+Sin[y2[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*y2[t]]+Sin[y3[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*y3[t]])),

y2'[t]==(k/n)*((Sin[-y2[t]+a]-r*Sin[-2*y2[t]]+Sin[y1[t]-y2[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(y1[t]-y2[t])]+Sin[y3[t]-y2[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(y3[t]-y2[t])]) - (Sin[y1[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*y1[t]]+Sin[y2[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*y2[t]]+Sin[y3[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*y3[t]])),

y3'[t]==(k/n)*((Sin[-y3[t]+a]-r*Sin[-2*y3[t]]+Sin[y1[t]-y3[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(y1[t]-y3[t])]+Sin[y2[t]-y3[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*(y2[t]-y3[t])]) - (Sin[y1[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*y1[t]]+Sin[y2[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*y2[t]]+Sin[y3[t]+a]-r*Sin[2*y3[t]]))
};
```

That is, I expect the solution for `y1` to look like that of `x2-x1`, `y2` to look like that of `x3-x1`, and `y3` to look like that of `x4-x1`. However, solving them as below and plotting the solution gives:

```
ics={x1[0]==0, x2[0]==0.1, x3[0]==0.2, x4[0]==0.3};
icsPD={y1[0]==0.1, y2[0]==0.2, y3[0]==0.3};
eqsics=Join[eqs, ics];
eqsicsPD=Join[eqsPD, icsPD];
SolutionValue[t_]=NDSolveValue[eqsics,{x1[t],x2[t],x3[t],x4[t]},{t,0,15000}];
SolutionValuePD[t_]=NDSolveValue[eqsicsPD,{y1[t],y2[t],y3[t]},{t,0,15000}];
```

[image]

Where I have plotted `x4-x1` in blue and `y3` in dashed orange. I have tried increasing the `AccuracyGoal` to infinity so that I can work with the `WorkingPrecision` and `PrecisionGoal` instead, but doing this seems to always return that `A component of the solution at t==0 is essentially zero and the tolerance specified by the AccuracyGoal option could not be achieved`. Attempting to set `WorkingPrecision` returns that `The precision of the differential equation is less than the WorkingPrecision` for any value I seem to try.

In general, inconsistencies between the two systems seem to occur for values of `a` between `1.1` and `1.5`, but otherwise they seem to be identical. I know that there are some SNIC or Hopf bifurcations in this parameter range that I imagine are related to why the system is so difficult to integrate for these values. Are there other approaches to solving this system more accurately that I am missing? Changing `MaxStepSize` to something smaller like `0.0001` has helped, however the computation starts to become rather expensive. Is continually decreasing the step size the best option or are there better approaches? And why / how is this occurring? Thank you for your time.